# Why was this version of the Stark vs Loki scene abandoned?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers

So recently I found [**this**](http://www.movieweb.com/movie/marvels-the-avengers/pre-viz-animatic-of-tony-suitup) little animation that seems to be taken from either deleted scenes or some sort of pre-processing/concept work up of the scene before the Battle of New York of Stark vs Loki.

[Warning:  Video is not on YouTube & takes a while to load, the clip is also 6 min long, I also can't guarantee that this is an official clip at all]

In this scene, it gives us a slight glimpse into what Loki does to manipulate his victims as it plays out and gives us a completely different dialogue path still leading upto Loki tossing Stark out of the window and obtaining his suit in free-fall.

By showing a more 'cerebral' side of Loki, other than [**his poking spree**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2513/why-didnt-lokis-mind-control-work-on-tony-stark) it also shows a more 'believable' (in a *very* loose sense of the word) way of Stark resisting the mind control by basically saying he has abused *wayyyy* too many substances.

First things first, is this even a real deleted clip?

If so, why was this angle of Loki seemingly abandoned/why was this scene removed for the poking?

Comment: Some of the dialogue is subtitled as *"and I kilt a bahr when I was only Three"*, so it's unlikely its official; or at least the dialogue could have been mistranslated. Either way it doesn't bode well for its legitimacy, m'fraid. Unless this is some oblique reference to Davy Crockett (which isn't neccesarily beyond Whedon, actually) or that line doesn't belong there.

Comment: Yeah, that's why my prelim question is if it's even real or some fan-made piece :D

Comment: If this *is* official (and TBH it seems impressive and I hardly think a snarky Stark joke discredits it), it's possible that the evil\corrupt Jarvis angle has been pulled from the 1st Avengers for use in the 2nd.

Answer (score 3):

After watching that video, my personal feeling is that it doesn't quite fit the rest of the movie.  Loki isn't shown to be a master manipulator in the movie.  Sure, he's got a bit of a silver tongue at times, but we never seem him do any direct mind control and we never see him truly convince someone to go against their nature without the spear.  This scene basically betrays how Loki was set up in the rest of the movie.  A sniveling kid given a new toy bent on world domination to prove to his father that he's better than him.