# Why didn't Loki realize he is touching the arc reactor?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers

I saw the answers of [this other question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2513/why-didnt-lokis-mind-control-work-on-tony-stark) about the scene in *The Avengers* where Loki tries to do his mind control on Tony Stark, so I started to wonder that why Loki didn't realize that he just has to move his staff to another body part of Tony.

I mean is Tony having an arc reactor a big secret? Because Loki seems to have much knowledge about the Avengers and earth. Loki is not as hot-headed as his brother, he must realize this at least.

Comment: While I somewhat agree with the 2nd part (Loki did seem rather informed about the group), I *think* he couldn't just move his staff because it had to be over the heart?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the Iron Man and Iron Man 2  movies, Tony's chest reactor is ***not*** public knowledge. At no time is it revealed to the public at large. Loki is not omniscient and had no way of knowing about it. Nor does Loki know how the scepter works 100%, other wise he would have taken the mind stone (one of six of the most powerful objects known to Asgardians.)

Additionally, it's implied that Loki is also under mind control throughout *The Avengers*. It's not stated out right, but Loki exhibits the same symptoms as Clint and Dr. Selvig do, up until he gets "cognitive recalibration" courtesy of the Hulk. The implication being that he can't think as well as he normally would.

Comment: "one of five of the most powerful objects known to Asgardians". There are 6 Infinity Stones. Also, there is no implication that Loki is under mind control in *The Avengers/Avengers Assemble*.

Comment: Fixed. And as I said, implied. It's a common interpretation of Loki ' s actions.

Comment: I don't have a lot of memories of IM2 (trying to suppress them and all) but are you sure the *chestpiece* at least wasn't common knowledge after Tony revealed his true identity (and it was glowing under his shirts and all that)?

Comment: @Walt I remember IM3 he tells the kid about it as if it's a secret. And aside from telling everyone he's Iron Man he doesn't give technical specs or anything. The plot point in 2 was that he doesn't share the tech because he's afraid of it being turned into a weapon and that's why Rhodes steals the Mark 2 for the government.

Comment: When is it implied that Loki is being mind controlled?